# WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Tags: python, flask, websocket, azure-application-gateway

We have host python service on the server (no public accessible) which allows HTTPS and Web Socket requests on *4431*.To connect to the python service, we have implemented an Azure App Gateway (bind with the domain) with rule - domain:4431 and which will be redirected to the server.

So, the problem is we are facing the following error

> **502 Bad Gateway - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2**

We have observed that request from the browser comes to the AppGW but on server, we are receiving request intermittently.

```
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=4431, certfile=certs["crt"], keyfile=certs["key"], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

Our Architecture
[image: Image: Our Architecture]

Error

[image]

Comment: Can you check the Backend Health status from the Portal ? If it showing unhealthy, please post the message which is displayed.

Comment: Found out, what causing the problem, we haven't provide ca_certs to run server.
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=4431, certfile=certs["crt"], keyfile=certs["key"], ca_certs=certs["CA-crt"], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

Comment: @JigarSuthar Please consider posting your solution as an answer. It helps other people with a similar issue find the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, what was causing the issue, we haven't provided root CA Certificate to run server.

```
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=4431, certfile=certs["crt"], keyfile=certs["key"], ca_certs=certs["CA crt"], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```